# Revs go up, but car doesn't increase in speed while shifting. Trouble accelerating

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, acceleration, opel, gm

I have a 1.2L Corsa B automatic, and I'm having trouble accelerating.  I can only get to 60 mph slowly on flat roads, and about 30-40 on a hill but 70-80 mph downhill.  I can feel it hesitating when changing gears, and revs go up but car won't increase in speed.

I've put in a new air filter and am running a cat cleaner through it.  Any ideas what it could be and what else I can do? Could it be the spark plugs or the fuel filter?

Comment: Well, I suggest do a complete service - bits and pieces is not the best way, aslo check the trans fluid level then re-evaluate as you are starting from a known baseline.

Comment: Hi Richard. This phrase is important: "revs go up but car won't increase in speed." Could you edit your question to provide as much information as possible about details related to this quote? All gears? Only once you've reached 60 mph? That sort of thing will help us diagnose what sounds like it could be a transmission problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!